# select if not a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a 3 tables Product, sku and option

Product

```
 ID                                            FlatID    Name
 314E5E5E-0A7E-4DC5-872C-16DA8DA36439          0706      Jacket
```

SKU

```
ID                                           productID                              QTY
6CFE849A-4856-43E8-9837-3B1D1122A701         314E5E5E-0A7E-4DC5-872C-16DA8DA36439     1
F76C9B5B-CEB5-44FE-AD27-69C4A3C124AE         314E5E5E-0A7E-4DC5-872C-16DA8DA36439     1
BB413DE8-E310-4393-95E9-8262D6EE515A         314E5E5E-0A7E-4DC5-872C-16DA8DA36439     1
866CD899-F25F-4C4D-9E56-A4A95A7BDC5D         314E5E5E-0A7E-4DC5-872C-16DA8DA36439     1
```

Options

```
skuid                                    OptionID                                 name    
6CFE849A-4856-43E8-9837-3B1D1122A701     1C823E53-EE98-4B22-8118-287BCA55C4D8       BK           
6CFE849A-4856-43E8-9837-3B1D1122A701     6D7168A0-775A-4C5B-B8E8-8CE3AF8A8665       LG           
F76C9B5B-CEB5-44FE-AD27-69C4A3C124AE     1C823E53-EE98-4B22-8118-287BCA55C4D8      BK           
F76C9B5B-CEB5-44FE-AD27-69C4A3C124AE     F6A0974C-303D-4C6A-8CE1-39071C7DF566      MD         
BB413DE8-E310-4393-95E9-8262D6EE515A     FB4D7BC1-6C71-4E00-8C85-0DE93DC1C531       SM         
BB413DE8-E310-4393-95E9-8262D6EE515A     1C823E53-EE98-4B22-8118-287BCA55C4D8      BK           
866CD899-F25F-4C4D-9E56-A4A95A7BDC5D     F6E0FB61-047E-4356-B085-630B38CBC7F2      XL
```

How to select SKU which don't have a one of option - for example in this case SKU `866CD899-F25F-4C4D-9E56-A4A95A7BDC5D` don't have a color option with name BK - but should.

Sometimes product(SKU) have a one or two or three options - and how find a SKU which don't have a some of option - may be need to get max count and compare but i dont know. ThanX

For example one product have a 2 sku one of them have a tree option - other one have a one option how to show that have not max option for SKU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually prefer left outer joins for this problem where you are getting all the rows in table A, in this case SKU, regardless of there is a match in B, or options. then use the where clause to filter out the matches so you are left with only skus without options.

```
SELECT SKU.*
FROM SKU
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Options
        ON Options.skuid = SKU.id
WHERE Options.skuid IS NULL
```

Comment: It is better to have a brief blurb explaining what you did than to just drop in code...

Comment: Good point.. Sorry i am still new. Thanks for the feedback. I have added details to help.

Comment: Tell me pls why is it should be NULL if it just don't have a row - it's doesn't work

Comment: Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a03d/1/0) for the example, but had to add a row into SKU table that didn't have an option since the sample data all had options. The NULL is used so that only SKUs are returned if there are no options due to the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @JasonW - Since there is no need of option table data in results it is always better to use NOT EXISTS than left join/IS NULL which return all results before filtering out the null values

Comment: I think both are perfectly valid as long as you are careful to write the NOT EXISTS so that it causes a table scan for each row. Performance is nearly identical. Both produce a Hash Match on the execution plan with the difference between a RIGHT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT ANTI SEMI JOIN. The NOT EXISTS for 8MM records in a non-scientific quick test was only a few ms faster than OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want any details of option table you just want check whether skuid present in option table so..

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sku A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   options 
                   WHERE  options.skuid = A.skuid)
```